# stty doesn't display backward-delete-word shortcut

Tags: line-editor, stty

```
stty -a
```

shows,

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 39; columns 143; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
```

Here, i am not seeing `M-DEL` which is the [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Words.html) styled shortcut for delete one word backward.

What is the stty subcommand i can use to remap the key for `backward-delete-word`?

Comment: It's ^W. And ^U for the whole line. Why do you have eol and wol2 set to the same thing? And swtch? Weird.

Comment: i didn't change anything for eol, wol2... i never use them, and in fact, don't know what those abbreviations are

Comment: Well, that was a typo. They're End of Line and End of Line 2. They're mapped to Mod-Delete, it looks like - octal 377 or decimal byte 255. I guess probably your terminal or getty script or whatever set it up that way. try: `(trap "stty $(stty -g;stty eol A)" 0; cat)`; then type an *`A`* and try to backspace over it. Use CTRL+D or CTRL+C to quit `cat`. Or `(trap "stty $(stty -g;stty -echo eol A)" 0; cat)` and type some stuff without entering a newline, then type *`A`* and see what happens. Usually those are null or `\0` or `^-` by default as far as I'm aware - so unassigned - but yours are set.

Answer (score 1):

M-Del is just an emacs key binding.  It's not something typically interpreted by the in-kernel tty driver.  Backwards word erase, or werase, is set to control-W (^W) in your `stty -a` output.

The kernel works on bytes, and so if you use a UTF-8 encoding, it will be hard to bind non-ASCII characters to werase.  In fact, M-Del would be 0xff, which is a byte that never appears in UTF-8.

Your best bet is to use a shell like bash or tcsh that puts the terminal in cbreak mode to implement its own line editing capabilities.  Bash seems to bind M-Del to word erase by default.  You can also run `bind -P` in bash to see what keys are bound to what editing functions.

Comment: Note that `bash` key bindings don't have any effect on input to other programs, unless those programs also make use of the `readline` library.