# Bind C-j to backward-kill-word, says command not found

Tags: bash, stty, xbindkeys

```
bind -x '"\C-j": backward-kill-word'
```

says,

```
backward-kill-word: command not found
```

As [mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218743/stty-doesnt-display-backward-delete-word-shortcut) quoted here, i am able to do `backward-kill-word` using `Ctrl-w`. However this is the same key i use in emacs for `select/cut` text, causing confusion.

I am trying to bind `backward-kill-word` to a different key sequence, `C-j` and got this error `command not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bind -x
```

expects a shell command. Just do

```
bind '"\C-j": backward-kill-word'
```